# Create htpasswd SHA1 password in powershell

Tags: powershell, sha1, .htpasswd

I want to create a htpasswd password, based on SHA1, in PowerShell.

Using the word "test" as password I have tested various functions and always get the SHA1 value:

```
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

Testing this in a htpasswd file

```
user:{SHA}a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

I am not able to login.

Using an online htpasswd generator. For example https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/ I get

```
user:{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
```

Which works just fine.

At first I thought I need to do a base64 en/decoding, but that is not the case.

Anybody an idea on how to get from "test" to "qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M="?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first I thought I need to do a base64 en/decoding

That is *indeed* the case! But it's not the string "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3" that you need to encode, it's the underlying byte array it represents

```
$username = 'user'
$password = 'test'

# Compute hash over password
$passwordBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($password)
$sha1 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1]::Create()
$hash = $sha1.ComputeHash($passwordBytes)

# Had we at this point converted $hash to a hex string with, say:
#
#   [BitConverter]::ToString($hash).ToLower() -replace '-'
#
# ... we would have gotten "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3"


# Convert resulting bytes to base64
$hashedpasswd = [convert]::ToBase64String($hash)

# Generate htpasswd entry
"${username}:{{SHA}}${hashedpasswd}"
```